# send data from raspberry to firebase cloud

Tags: c++, arduino, raspberry-pi, firebase-realtime-database, iot

Hey i'm new in Firebase and I have a question.
First i will talk about the project and what I want to do. We have a organery with many sensors, those sensors are connected to arduino's. We have some arduino's who are connected to a raspberry by serial communication using an I2C connection. **Then we want to send that data to the firebase cloud**. But honestly i have no clue how i have to do that. That data from the cloud we use to make an app to see the "climate" of our arganery.

Our program in arduino is made in C++, and the raspberry code is also in C++. Any ideas to get that data into the firebase cloud? Thank You for reading!

Greeting Iben

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you please describe what you have tried so far? Please remember, SO is no coding service. You have to provide some input in form of code, concept etc. that people can help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have sent data to Firebase by first publishing data to an MQTT (Mosquitto), and then using [Node-RED](http://nodered.org/) with a [Firebase node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-firebase) to store data in Firebase.

Currently I am only storing the latest value in Firebase, but sure you can also store history. Node-RED is a very powerful and easy to use tool for IoT.

You can run bot Mosquitto and Node-RED on your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But I think is solved my problem. At the moment I am using Python to get the data to the firebase. But I will take a look at your solution!